# check if numbers from command line are powers of 2

Tags: bash, scripting

i can`t make a bash script who check if a input numbers in command line is an power of 2

input

```
# ./pow2script.sh xyzdf 4 8 12 -2 USAD
```

desired output : the desire output should be on separated lines

```
4
8
```

because only 4 is 2^2
and 8 is 2^3

content of pow2script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function is_power_of_two () {
    declare -i n=$1
    (( n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0 ))
}

for number; do
    if is_power_of_two "$number"; then
        printf "%d\n" "$number"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Show us the content of `powerscript.sh` (post in the question itself)

Comment: A `mod` only gives the remainder, so any even number mod 2 is 0.

Comment: you could show the code exactly to understand please

Comment: You need to make use of positional parameters in bash to pass arguments from the cli (here's a good read: https://gerardnico.com/lang/bash/argument).

Comment: i am baging you post code please i try many times but not working

Comment: Since you mention Linux, you probably have the `factor` command.  eg `factor 32` will return `32: 2 2 2 2 2`.  You could check the output and determine if it just contains 2's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number is a power of 2 if its [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) is exactly 1.

To calculate a number's Hamming weight is the same as calculate the number of 1s in its binary representation.

The following is a short `bash` script that does that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop over all numbers on the command line
# note: we don't verify that these are in fact numbers
for number do
    w=0         # Hamming weight (count of bits that are 1)
    n=$number   # work on $n to save $number for later

    # test the last bit of the number, and right-shift once
    # repeat until number is zero
    while (( n > 0 )); do
        if (( (n & 1) == 1 )); then
            # last bit was 1, count it
            w=$(( w + 1 ))
        fi

        if (( w > 1 )); then
            # early bail-out: not a power of 2
            break
        fi

        # right-shift number
        n=$(( n >> 1 ))
    done

    if (( w == 1 )); then
        # this was a power of 2
        printf '%d\n' "$number"
    fi
done
```

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh xyzdf 4 8 12 -2 USAD
4
8
```

Note: There are more efficient ways to do this, and `bash` is a *particularly* bad choice of language for it.

---

Since it's come up a few times in a short time (this appears to be a homework assignment or some other type of exercise):

- I will not modify this code to skip the number `1` if it occurs in the input.
- I will not make it output the sum of the numbers in any form.
- I will not describe the algorithm further than what's already been done in the comments.

Comment: men, should be modify the code because when i run ./powerscript.sh xyz 4 8 -2 he show 4 , 8 but not corectly when i have char

Comment: @AndrewThe script will not output the string since its not even a number. This is exactly the behaviour that you describe in your updated question.

Comment: so , the input is ./powerscript.sh xyz 4 -2 uso 8 63 ASDASD and i want to show on seprated lines on numbers which are power of two but the command line will be entered with xyz and ASDASD

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand. Is this not the current behaviour of this script?

Comment: when i check the output i have a checker and checker say:the numbers that represent the powers of the two are not correctly displayed, have you any ideas?

Comment: @Andrew Unless I can look at the checker, I would not know what it expects.

Answer (score 13):

There's a nice shortcut to check that a number is a power of two.

If you represent such a number in binary, it will be a single 1 followed by a string of zeroes, for instance `0b100000` for the number 32. If you subtract one from it, you'll get ones where you had the zeroes and a zero where you had the 1, for instance `0b011111` for the number 31, which is 32 - 1. If you do a bitwise and operation on these two, you'll get a zero. That property is only valid on numbers that are powers of two (and zero).

So:

```
function is_power_of_two () {
    declare -i n=$1
    (( n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0 ))
}
```

Use it as:

```
for number; do
    if is_power_of_two "$number"; then
        printf "%d\n" "$number"
    fi
done
```

And execution output:

```
$ ./power2.sh 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 31 32 33 -2
1
2
4
8
32
```

Comment: this is very clever

Comment: i have a checker bro and he said im not displaying corectly the numbers which is power of 2 can you have any ideas to get the points when i check

Comment: that's a real beauty =}

Answer (score 4):

Another pure bash approach

```
isPowerOf2 () {
    local n=$1 i=0
    for ((; n>1; n/=2, i++)); do :; done
    (($1 - (2 ** $i) == 0))
}
```

and

```
$ for n in {1..17}; do isPowerOf2 $n && echo $n; done
1
2
4
8
16
```

Or looking at the octal representation of the number:

```
isPowerOf2() {
    local octal=$(printf %o "$1" 2>/dev/null) && 
      [[ $octal -eq 4 || $octal =~ ^[12]0*$ ]]
}
```

Or awk perhaps

```
$ seq 17 | awk '{lg = log($1) / log(2)} lg == int(lg)'
1
2
4
8
16
```

Comment: i try this code but generate errors

Comment: which code? what errors?

Comment: syntax error near unexpected

Comment: Is your script using `#!/bin/bash` ? Are you invoking it like `sh myscript.sh 4 8 foo`?

Comment: yes , sure im using

Comment: Well, you'll have to show more details about the error. I don't see it. What version are you using? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: when i check the output i have a checker and checker say:the numbers that represent the powers of the two are not correctly displayed, have you any ideas?

Comment: 1. without seeing the check, no; 2. I now have 3 different solutions in my answer, which are you using?

Comment: you can post the entire code in one comment because I'm afraid I omitted something in the code

Comment: What are you talking about? You need to show **your** code so I can help you fix it.

Comment: check the content of powerscript.sh in description above

Comment: That looks correct. Do you have errors? If yes, edit your question to show **exactly** how you are running that script, and show **exactly** what the error messages are. Cut and paste from your terminal is best.

Answer (score 2):

Got the `factor` command? Try

```
factor $number | sed 's/^[^:]*:\|[2 ]//g;'
```

and test for empty result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ is_power_of_two(){ printf '%x' "$1" | grep -q '^[1248]0*$'; }
$ powers_of_two(){ printf '%#x\n' "$@" | grep '^0x[1248]0*$' | xargs -I@ printf '%d\n' @; }

$ powers_of_two `seq 1 1000000`
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
...
```

On some systems (eg. busybox) `xargs` doesn't support the standard `-I` option, but does support the GNU `-r` (no run if empty) option:

```
powers_of_two(){ test "$1" && printf '%#x\n' "$@" | grep '^0x[1248]0*$' | xargs -r printf '%d\n'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If only for bash, this shall work:

```
#!/bin/bash
powers_of_two(){
    sum=0
    for n                          # for every argument from the command line.
    do

    [[ $n =~ ^0*([0-9]+)$ ]] ||    # check that the argument only has base 10 digits.
        continue                   # If not go to next number.

    n=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}           # Remove all of the leading zeros.

    (( n>0 && !(n&(n-1)) )) &&     # Is n positive and a power of 2.
        printf '%d %d\n' "$n" "$((sum+=n))"        # print the number
                                                   # and the sum as integer
                                                   # numbers in base 10.

    done
}


powers_of_two -22 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 08 00008 9 31 32 33 -2 asd fhgh 2+2 3e3 inf
```

If executed:

```
$ ./script
1 1
2 3
4 7
8 15
8 23
8 31
32 63
```