# Check pow of 2 with restriction

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to write a condition so if the argument is 1 ( which is 2 ^ 0 = 1 ) it will jump over it. 
For example:

```
powsnsums 1 2 8
```

2

```
powsnsums 1 16
```

1

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop over all numbers on the command line
# note: we don't verify that these are in fact numbers
for number do
    w=0         # Hamming weight (count of bits that are 1)
    n=$number   # work on $n to save $number for later

    # test the last bit of the number, and right-shift once
    # repeat until number is zero
    while (( n > 0 )); do
        if (( (n & 1) == 1 )); then
            # last bit was 1, count it
            w=$(( w + 1 ))
        fi

        if (( w > 1 )); then
            # early bail-out: not a power of 2
            break
        fi

        # right-shift number
        n=$(( n >> 1 ))
    done

    if (( w == 1 )); then
        # this was a power of 2
        printf '%d\n' "$number"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Whatever you guys use this code for (it seems to be quite popular), I hope that you give proper attribution, https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/

Comment: `powsnums(){ printf '%#x\n' "$@" | egrep '^0x([248]0*|10+)$' | xargs -I@ printf '%d\n' @; }`

Comment: @mosvy The `1` is also a power of `2`: `2^0`. ... Why all external utilities: grep xargs printf ? Why not the faster internal (at least for ksh-bash-zsh): `powsum(){ sum=0; for n; do (( (n&(n-1)) )) || printf '%s\n' "$n $((sum+=n))"; done; }`.

Comment: 1. because of the 'restriction' from OP's question; read my original [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482843/308316). 2. because it's not faster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$number" -eq 1 ]; then
    continue
fi
```

or

```
if (( number == 1 )); then
    continue
fi
```

This would make the loop skip to the next iteration if `$number` is numerically equal to 1.  The test would go just beneath the `for number do` line.